# Contact prfile in CRM opens from SSRS report viewer but not when report runs from within CRM

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am facing strange issue here, need your help to get rid of this!

I made a report in SSRS with several parameters to get the report results. Report is working fine.

So when I get report result I added expression for "Client Name" field via, text box properties -> Action-> Go to URL in SSRS and it's working it opens that perticualr client profile  in CRM.

My URL in SSRS when user clicks on Client Name which opens Client's profile in CRM is as below.(e.g. Following link is for Client with Name "Peter")

https://crm.abc.com/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id=067723cc-4211-e611-8124-005056a66018#218084066

Now when I upload this report to CRM->Solution->My Solution->Report->Upload existing file and make it such way that it shows up in "Ad-Hoc" which is custom tile in CRM which we have created. So after uploading this report's RDL file, it runs fine, I get my results as well but when I click on Client's name it gives me

*404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

And my URL becomes now as follows instead of above which works fine.

https://crm.abc.com/CRMReports/viewer/drillopen.aspxetn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id=067723cc-4211-e611-8124-005056a66018

It looks like when I upload report and run it within CRM it adds few things into URL (if yous see above you will know, like CRMReports/viewer/drillopen.aspx) and that's the reason why I guess it's giving me that "404- File or directory not found error"

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, here is the solution.

Put following for CRM_URL parameter in SSRS report.
https://crm.abc.com/CRMReports/viewer/drillopen.aspx

AND when you click on client's name in table put following into Action under text box properties.

Parameters!CRM_URL.Value & "?ID={" & Fields!ClientId.Value.ToString() & "}&OTC=2"